How to install undetected-chromedriver on Python?
I eventually installed it using the command:
python3 -m pip install undetected_chromedriver

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\2_qatar\tws.py", line 1, in <module>
    import undetected_chromedriver as uc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'undetected_chromedriver'


Replace _ by -:
pip install undetected-chromedriver

https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver
